# How to change workspace used to install python packages in IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have a python project in IntelliJ 2021.2.3, using poetry as dependency manager. I have [poetry plugin](https://koxudaxi.github.io/poetry-pycharm-plugin/) and [python plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631-python) installed.

I recently renamed this project from `old_project_name` to `new_project_name`. I renamed my project's directory, project name in `pyproject.toml` file and I've updated the name in Intellij's project structure:

- `File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Project > Project Name`
- `File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules > Name`

Now I want to install pytest support for intelliJ in this project. So I followed the steps described in [Jetbrain's documentation for setting up pytest](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/pytest.html)

- go to `Tools > Manage Python Packages`
- search `pytest`
- click `install`

However install fails with the following error message:

> Cannot start process, the working directory '/home/user/projects/old_project_name' does not exist

**How can I change this working directory, currently set to `/home/user/projects/old_project_name`, to the one corresponding to my new project name `/home/user/projects/new_project_name` ?**

An easy solution would be to delete and recreate my project, but I'm wondering if there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TDLR: I solved this issue by recreating my project's virtualenv using poetry plugin**

##### What created my issue ?

When I renamed my project, I didn't change my project virtual environment that I've created using poetry plugin. This virtual environment, although it looks like it is a global virtual environment, is actually linked to the project. You can see that if you look at virtual environment definition in IntelliJ config, in file `~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/options/jdk.table.xml`, there is an `ASSOCIATED_PROJECT_PATH` element that explicitly contains the project's path:

```xml
 <application>
  <component name="ProjectJdkTable">
    <jdk version="2">
      <name value="Poetry (old_project_name)" />
      <type value="Python SDK" />
      <version value="Python 3.10.0" />
      <homePath value="$USER_HOME$/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/old_project_name-HdcC6q8N-py3.10/bin/python" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root url="file:///usr/local/lib/python3.10" type="simple" />
            <root url="file:///usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/old_project_name-HdcC6q8N-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/python_stubs/95207232" type="simple" />
            <root url="file://$APPLICATION_PLUGINS_DIR$/python/helpers/python-skeletons" type="simple" />
            ...
            <root url="file://$APPLICATION_PLUGINS_DIR$/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-dateutil" type="simple" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
      <additional ASSOCIATED_PROJECT_PATH="$USER_HOME$/projects/old_project_name" IS_POETRY="true" />
    </jdk>
  </component>
</application>
```

Thus I was unable to install new dependencies on a virtual environment of a project that doesn't exist anymore.

##### How I solved it

When you rename your project, you should recreate a new virtual environment and link it to your project, by following the steps below:

- Go to `File > Project Structure`
- Select `Platform Settings > SDKs` in the left menu
- Click on the `+` in the top-left corner and select `Add Python SDK...`
- Select `Poetry Environment` in the left menu
- Click `Ok` in bottom-right corner, it creates the SDK called `Poetry (new_project_name)`
- Select `Project Settings > Project`
- Select SDK `Poetry (new_project_name)` instead of `Poetry (old_project_name)` in `Project SDK` dropdown menu
- Click on `Apply` in bottom-right corner

With that, you're all set and you can install new python packages without `Cannot start process, the working directory '...' does not exist` error

Answer (score 0):

- turn off intellij
- change your project name
- go to project name folder and search in some file manager all occurrences of old_project_name and rename to new name.
  Then go to intellij, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I didn't find any occurence of my old project name in intelliJ project's configuration files. However, I found occurences in IntelliJ global configuration files, leading me to the solution.